# SendGrid Protocol Violation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I am having a problem using SendGrid in my ASP.NET MVC application I have tried several different configurations but keep getting this error

> The server committed a protocol violation The server response was:
>
> Status Code = GeneralFailure

Here is the code:

```
var mail = new MailMessage(@"donotreply@xxxxxx.com", message.Destination);
mail.Subject = message.Subject;
mail.Body = message.Body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("wxxxxxxx", "Jxxxxxxxxxxx");  // using my SendGrid username and password

using (SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net", 587))
{
    client.Credentials = credentials;
    try
    {
            await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
    catch (SmtpException ex)
    {                       
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());     
    }

}
```

Has anyone else had this problem or can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some complementary information.

1. you need activate your account. In my case more the 6h SendGrid
2. Your pwd will be in base64
3. This error **UGFzc3dvcmQ6** means "Password:" base 64 encoded

Answer (score 0):

I used telnet to determine that my account password was not correct. After resetting my password the code worked fine. I guess that the "protocol violation" error threw me off.